# Sed using extended regexp and capture groups

Tags: regex, sed

I wrote the following sed one liner for substituting the 3rd portion of an IP address.

```
sed 's/192\.168\.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/192.168.15.\1/g'

192.168.0.1
192.168.15.1
```

I want to make it lazy so it would replace `192.168.0` with `192.168.15` by using `??` which is extended regexp but when I supply the '-r' option I get the following error.

```
$ sed -r 's/192\.168\.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/192.168.15.\1/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Can you explain what is going on here and how to make an expression lazy whilst using capture groups?

*Note: I can achieve the example using many different approaches, my question isn't how to solve the example. I am interesting in using sed with exteneded regexp and capture groups.*

Comment: N.B. `sed -r 's/192\.168(\.[0-9]*){2}/192.168.15\1/g'` achieves the same result, the back reference `\1` returns the second of the two `(\.[0-9]*){2}` and avoids the duplication of the regexp.

Comment: That is cleaner, also helps when making expression lazy `sed -r 's/192\.168(\.??[0-9]*){2}/192.168.15\1/g'` as it deals with the trailing `.` for the 3 portion case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no need to escape braces because `([0-9]*)` is valid statement matching group of symbols.

```
$> echo "192.168.0.1" | sed -r 's/192\.168\.[0-9]*\.([0-9]*)/192\.168\.15\.\1/g'
192.168.15.1
```

Comment: Note that if you're replacing in a file, using -ir may not work. If that's the case, you need to pass the options separately, as in `sed -i -r 's/.../.../ file'` (or using the spelled out versions: `sed --in-place --regexp-extended 's/.../.../ file'`).